# define method to create method that accept variable

Tags: ruby

i have a question regarding define method .
I have this class

```
class A
  def create_method(name,&block)
    self.class.send(:define_method, name, &block)
  end
end

a = A.new
a.create_method("dyn_meth") {puts "this is dynamic method"}
a.dyn_meth
```

i manage to create method name "dyn_meth" , but now i want to create method name "dyn_meth2" that accept variable in normal case is :

```
def dyn_meth2(var1,var2,&block)
    puts "var1 = #{var1} . var2 #{var2}
    block.call
end
```

how can i use define_method to create "dyn_meth2"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comme ca!

```
a.create_method("dyn_meth2") { |var| puts "var is #{var}" }
a.dyn_meth2("monkey")
#=> "var is monkey"
```

And if you want to have defaults on your arg then you do like this

```
a.create_method("dyn_meth2") { |var=2| puts "var is #{var}" }
a.dyn_meth2
#=> "var is 2"
```

and last but not least, you want varargs

```
a.create_method("dyn_meth2") { |*args| puts "var is #{args}" }
a.dyn_meth2(1,2,3)
#=> "var is [1,2,3]
```

Comment: You're missing closing quotes in your last two `create_method` parameters. Someone didn't actually run the code and paste the output into the examples. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
a.create_method("dyn_meth2") {|var1, var2, &block| 
   puts "var1 = #{var1} . var2 #{var2}"
   block.call 
}
```